# identity forKey values in animationDidStop

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, subview, uiviewanimation

I have several animations and I want get value of addAnimation name and forKey value in animationDidStop. any of you knows how can I get those values?

```
 [subView.layer addAnimation:group forKey:@"flightAnimation"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following in your animationDidStop event to retreive the animation object for a key and check implicitly for non-nil:

```
if (yourAnimation == [[subView layer] animationForKey: @"flightAnimation"]) {...}
```

But this would only work i think, if you explicitly set the `removedOnCompletion` property of your animation to `NO`. If not, your animation will get removed before when it completes and the callback will not find it.

Why do you want to get the animations key name in the first place?
What would you like to do with it, the key name is not going to change under your feet for some reason?

Comment: I want to reuse the same animation and just replace the forKey to know what view I'm using and have different actions after the animation is done for each view. That was the reason I want it to know the values for "forKey" and addAnimation